# ModuleNotFoundError while importing a script into another to edit a variable

Tags: python, python-import, modulenotfounderror

I am trying to import a slave script so I can pass additional values to it from a master script. But, this slave script uses a certain module that is specific to a different software (CAD/FEM). When I try to use import slave_script an error "ModuleNotFoundError" pops up.

All i want to do is to read this file and edit a variable in it.

Are there are other ways to do it?

i have a script ansa_import_preview which uses a module called 'ansa'. This is specific to a software and i cannot install in my python environment.

I use the command:
#from slave_script import variable#

I get an error :
#ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansa'#

I want to read the script and edit a variable inside it and I dont know how to do it.

Comment: please include your code and the entire error you are getting back to get better help

Comment: i have a script ansa_import_preview which uses a module called ansa. This is specific to a software and i cannot install in my python environment.

I use the command:
#from ansa_import_preview import file_path#

I get an error :
#ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ansa'#

I want to read the script and edit a variable inside it and I dont know how to do it.

Comment: edit your initial question to reflect